# New style and symbol with ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I a beginner with the ArcGIS platform.

I would like to create a new style with ArcMap. I try with the menu : Customize -> Style Manager

Style Manager : http://hpics.li/9471c73

My new style appears but it seems to be empty. I would like to add new symbols on it. Exactly 12 images (png).

First of all, I don’t know where can I put them in all the different categories. None of them seems to accept images…Is this the good way to create a new style with new symbols on it ?

Symbol Selector : http://hpics.li/a01f07a

In the second windows, with the selection of the style, I would like to have in the empty windows all of my 12 new symbols. I would like to click on it to attribute them to a certain entities.

How can I make a new style with new symbols ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert pictures as symbols using the "Marker Symbol" in the style manager.

In the Style Manager, after you have created your new style, you need to locate the Marker Symbols folder.

You left-click with the mouse once and then move to the blank zone on the right.

Here you right-click with the mouse, choose "new" and then "Marker Symbols".

In the next window from the drop-down menu you need to choose "Picture Marker Symbol" and then select the proper one from your pc.

You will need to repeat these steps for all your 12 pictures.